# How to determine if a GPS coordinate lies within a rectangular area?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, gps, coordinates

I went through many similar questions on Stackoverflow and other websites and I based my solution on those answers but I still can't get it to work…

**My problem:** I want to determine whether or not a certain GPS location `P` lies within a rectangular area bounded by four given GPS coordinates `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

At the moment I am calculating the areas of triangles `ABP`, `BCP`, `CDP` and `DAP`. If any of those areas is bigger than zero (don't be upset, mathematicians) the point lies outside my rectangle as explained [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/03/09/algorithm-to-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-square-with-mathematics-no-hit-test-involved/).

Code:

```
private static double triangleArea(Location a, Location b, Location c) {
    // (C.x*B.y-B.x*C.y)-(C.x*A.y-A.x*C.y)+(B.x*A.y-A.x*B.y)
    double result = (c.getLongitude()*b.getLatitude()-b.getLongitude()*c.getLatitude())-(c.getLongitude()*a.getLatitude()-a.getLongitude()*c.getLatitude())+(b.getLongitude()*a.getLatitude()-a.getLongitude()*b.getLatitude());
    return result;
}

public static boolean isInsideSquare(Location a, Location b, Location c, Location d, Location p) {
    if (triangleArea(a,b,p)>0 || triangleArea(b,c,p)>0 || triangleArea(c,d,p)>0 || triangleArea(d,a,p)>0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when I call this function it's always returning `false`. Even when using the following coordinates (latitude, longitude):

```
A: (50.884706, 4.714151)
B: (50.884944, 4.716149)
C: (50.884679, 4.716228)
D: (50.884441, 4.714230)
P: (50.884538, 4.714615)
```

Yet when I plot those points on a map (e.g. [here](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html)) I can see that point P lies within ABCD… (see below)

[image]

I've read some easy solutions where you just subtract the x, y coordinates of your points, but that would obviously only work for rectangles parallel to the x-axis and y-axis, whereas my rectangle can be oriented in any angle.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or suggest a better solution to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the sizes involved can be large enough, note that you'll need to properly consider the fact that the earth is not a rectangle, but roughly spherical. Is this an issue?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle) on mathexchange.  I think the algorithm used in the example you linked might be more complicated than your needs.

Comment: @TimS. Yes I did consider that, but since the sizes would only go up to 50 meters maximum, I don't think it's worth taking into consideration.

Comment: @turbo I'll check that question and see if it can provide a solution.

Comment: Please, what is a rectangle on the spherical surface?

Comment: @Gangnus I agree that it sounds odd, but basically it's a geo fence. I just need to determine if a location is located within a rectangular area bounded by 4 coordinates. Since the areas are rather small, the fact the surface is spherical is negligible (see added screenshot). Even when calculating the surfaces of the 4 triangles and ensuring that the sum of those 4 is equal to the surface of the rectangle doesn't give me the expected result… Can it be due to the fact I'm using latitude and longitude?

Comment: It's been long time since my last geometry lesson but I noticed that you are calculating areas (which require distances) while using coordinates (which are angles). There should be a conversion along the lines (i.e. assuming earth's radius being constant) or you will have issues when the rectangle crosses equator or prime meridian

Comment: You don't strictly have a rectangle, but rather a tetragon (an arbitrary polygon with 4 sides). Your assumption that it is a rectangle may be the cause of your error.

Comment: The code you give also depends on the orientation of your rectangle (ABCD vs. DCBA). If you try the reverse calculation the point should lie inside. Another way is to test if all areas are either positive or all areas are negative. If they are mixed-sign the answer is false.

Comment: As for area, you should recount B,L to X,Y before. Or use another formulae, for geographical coordinates. Of course, no problems with equator or prime meridian crossing, but 180 degrees meridian or areas on poles are problematical. Also, check if it is really a rectangle, Bohemian is right.

Comment: Watch out for longitudes crossing 180, where for example 179.9 is between 179.8 and -179.8.

Answer (score 4):

## If a point is inside a rectangle. On a plane. For mathematician or geodesy (GPS) coordinates

- Lets prolong the sides of the rectangle. So we have 4 straight lines l<sub>AB</sub>, l<sub>BC</sub>, l<sub>CD</sub>, l<sub>DA</sub>, or, for shortness, l<sub>1</sub>, l<sub>2</sub>, l<sub>3</sub>, l<sub>4</sub>.
- Make an equation for every l<sub>i</sub>. The equation sort of:

  f<sub>i</sub>(P)=0.

*P is a point. For points, belonging to l<sub>i</sub>, the equation is true.*

- We need the functions on the left sides of the equations. They are f<sub>1</sub>, f<sub>2</sub>, f<sub>3</sub>, f<sub>4</sub>.
- Notice, that for every point from one side of l<sub>i</sub> the function f<sub>i</sub> is greater than 0, for points from the other side f<sub>i</sub> is lesser than 0.
- So, if we are checking for P being in rectangle, we only need for the p to be on correct sides of all four lines. So, we have to check four functions for their signs.
- But what side of the line is the correct one, to which the rectangle belongs? It is the side, where lie the vertices of rectangle that don't belong to the line. For checking we can choose anyone of two not belonging vertices.
- So, we have to check this:

  f<sub>AB</sub>(P) f<sub>AB</sub>(C) >= 0

  f<sub>BC</sub>(P) f<sub>BC</sub>(D) >= 0

  f<sub>CD</sub>(P) f<sub>CD</sub>(A) >= 0

  f<sub>DA</sub>(P) f<sub>DA</sub>(B) >= 0

*The unequations are not strict, for if a point is on the border, it belongs to the rectangle, too. If you don't need points on the border, you can change inequations for strict ones. But while you work in floating point operations, the choice is irrelevant.*

- For a point, that is in the rectangle, all four inequations are true. Notice, that it works also for every convex polygon, only the number of lines/equations will differ.
- The only thing left is to get an equation for a line going through two points. It is a well-known linear equation. Let's write it for a line AB and point P:

  f<sub>AB</sub>(P)   ≡  
  (x<sub>A</sub>-x<sub>B</sub>) (y<sub>P</sub>-y<sub>B</sub>) - (y<sub>A</sub>-y<sub>B</sub>) (x<sub>P</sub>-x<sub>B</sub>)

The check could be simplified - let's go along the rectangle **clockwise** - A, B, C, D, A. Then all correct sides will be to the right of the lines. So, we needn't compare with the side where another vertice is. And we need check a set of shorter inequations:

f<sub>AB</sub>(P) >= 0

f<sub>BC</sub>(P) >= 0

f<sub>CD</sub>(P) >= 0

f<sub>DA</sub>(P) >= 0

But this is correct for the normal, **mathematician** set of coordinates, where X is to the right and Y to the top. And for the **geodesy** coordinates, as are used in GPS, where X is to the top, and Y is to the right, we have to turn the inequations:

f<sub>AB</sub>(P) <= 0

f<sub>BC</sub>(P) <= 0

f<sub>CD</sub>(P) <= 0

f<sub>DA</sub>(P) <= 0

*If you are not sure with the directions of axis, be careful with this simplified check - check for one point manually, if you have chosen the correct inequations.*

---

BTW, the rectangle on the sphere has sense too. It is the area between two parallels and two meridians, of course, with any orientation of the main axis. But you don't need it, according to the comment.

Comment: Just for the understanding... You are using the crossproduct of two vectors (AB and AP f.e) to determine if the vector AP is in a clockwise direction to AB? Or not clockwise in the case of the vector BA. If this is true for all n vectors ( n is the amount of sides of the convex object ) the point P is in the object?

Comment: @SteveBenett No. When the very orientation of the system is not sure, you can't count on Vector multiplication and right hand rule. I use crossproduct (I am accustomed to the term "vector multiplication of vectors") when I am surely in mathematical coordinate system. And here - I simply checked formulas by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a point in polygon function. This always works, unless not overlapping the datum limit (180 to -180 jump) or at the poles.

I am curious which is faster, the approach from Gangnus or the point in poly. 
The Normal case is that points are far outside.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try the `java.awt.Rectangle` class.

```
public boolean contains(Point p)
```

Checks whether or not this `Rectangle` contains the specified `Point`.