# how to find point coordinate in between four point cordinate(Rectancle)

Tags: java, math, coordinates, point, rectangles

I want to find the point in between four points or not. Please help me, is there any algorithm??
I want to write in java program.

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the point in between four points or not"?  Are you referring to the intersection of the diagonals?

Comment: Use maths! First try to solve the mathematic problem (with pencil & paper) and finally try to convert it to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `java.awt.Polygon`.

```
public boolean contains(Point p)
```

Checks whether or not this `Polygon` contains the specified `Point`. It's algorithm is pretty fast. If you need an even faster approach, [read this](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=26013.0).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a rectangle called r, this r has an x position, y position, width and height.

The middle would be :

```
Point p = new Point(r.x + (r.width / 2), r.y + (r.height / 2));
```

To check if the point is inside the rectangle

```
if(p.x >= r.x && p.y >= r.y && p.x <= r.x + r.width && p.y <= r.y + r.height){
     //The point is inside the rectangle
}
```

To check if the point is inside the four points if the points where layed out like this :

```
   A  B
   C  D

   if(p.x >= a.x && p.y >= a.y && p.x <= b.x && p.y <= d.y){
         //The point is inside the points
   }
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to know. Given a Rectangle and another point p whether this point p lies within the Rectangle

Comment: @Montaldo Ok, I think he forgot a "if". I will add it

Comment: @thetheodor This is not rectangle, i having only 4 points(A(X,Y), B(x1,y1), C(x2, Y2), D(X3, Y3)). I want to search P(X4, Y4) in between this coordinate. It is in or not..

Comment: @NitinKarale Does this four points represent a rectangle?

Comment: @thetheodor No, Because this coordinates are longitude and latitude of geoppoints.

Comment: @NitinKarale Then you've to work with vectors.

Comment: @thetheodor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787743/how-to-determine-if-a-gps-coordinate-lies-within-a-rectangular-area

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54503/discussion-between-nitin-karale-and-thetheodor).

Comment: @NitinKarale Try to be more specific next time creating a question at stackoverflow, it helps everyone and you'll get an answer faster! Good luck!